# Control scroll view when having two listview

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I'm using uiautomator to turn on the WiFi switch and then connect to WiFi AP.
What I want to do is:

1. Turn on WiFi
2. Connect to WiFi AP

**But the problem is the setting page in tablet have two listview.**
When I turning on WiFi, I need to control the left listview.
And after that, I need to control the right listview to connect to my WiFi AP.

**I need to scroll to browse all listview item**, but I always fail to do so.
I did try to specify listview by instance(0) & instance(1), but sometimes it would fail.

Below is the code:

```
public void TurnOn()
{
    try {
        UiScrollable settingsList = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ListView.class.getName()).instance(0).scrollable(true));
        UiObject btItem = settingsList.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.LinearLayout.class.getName()),"Wi-Fi", true);
        UiObject btSwitch = btItem.getChild(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Switch.class.getName()));
        if(!btSwitch.isChecked())
        {
            btSwitch.click();
            sleep(3000);
        }
        else System.out.println("Wifi is already enabled");

    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find the Wi-Fi switch");
    }
}
public void ConnectAP()//No password Ap
{ 
    UiScrollable wifiList = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ListView.class.getName()).instance(1).scrollable(true));
    if(!wifiList.exists()) wifiList = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
    else System.out.println("Its tablet");

    UiSelector selector = new UiSelector().className(android.widget.RelativeLayout.class.getName());
    UiObject btItem = null;
    int maxSearchSwipes = wifiList.getMaxSearchSwipes();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSearchSwipes && i<10; i++) 
    {
        try {
            btItem = wifiList.getChildByText(selector, "Guest");
            if(btItem.getChildCount()==2) System.out.println("Wifi is already connected to Guest AP or not in range.");
            else {
                btItem.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();          
                sleep(3000);
            }
            break;
        } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) { //Do nothing    
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            try {
                wifiList.scrollForward();
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Can't scrollForward");
            }
        }
    }
    if(btItem == null) System.out.println("Can't find Guest AP.");
}
```

Most of the time it works, but sometime the code get control over the wrong listview.
Need some valuable suggestions.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out!

Change the original code

```
UiScrollable wifiList = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ListView.class.getName()).instance(1).scrollable(true));
```

into

```
UiScrollable wifiList = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ListView.class.getName()).instance(1));
```

And it works!